# RMS/quadratic mean and confidence interval

Tags: statistics, means, confidence-interval

After searching on the web without success, I'm asking for help here. I wasn't taught statistics, and I get lost in a lot of formulas that I often find hard to understand. I'm also not used to posting on a forum, let me know if I need to change anything, or give more details!

I'm following a protocol to get the performance of an algorithm.
I have measured its average performance *X_sample_mean* (arithmetic mean) on a population of n samples. I'd like to calculate a confidence interval to estimate the range within which the true mean may be found.
I followed the classic method of calculating uncertainty using the Student distribution, described in slide 10 of [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/A-G-Aravinna/publication/325756898_Basic_Concepts_of_Measurement_Uncertainty/links/5b22366d0f7e9b0e37408e58/Basic-Concepts-of-Measurement-Uncertainty.pdf) link.

This seems to work well, as you can see here the normal distribution associated with my measured mean *X_sample_mean*, and those associated with the uncertainty (here for a 95% confidence interval): [result_confidence_interval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK766.png)

My problem is: **I need to work with an RMS** (root mean square) **instead of an arithmetic mean**. Do you know please if this uncertainty calculation remain valid if I simply replace this arithmetic mean value with the RMS value I've measured? If not, how can I obtain the confidence interval associated with this RMS?

Thanks to those who read me.

Comment: Could this be a starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation#Normalization